# Heat Equation on LCA Group

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, harmonic-analysis, heat-equation

I am reading *The Laplacian on A Riemannian Manifold*. In the book, author defines the heat equation on manifold. In the situation $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb S$, people often use Fourier transformation and Fourier series to solve heat equations.

In addition, *A First Course in Harmonic Analysis* generalizes the conception of Fourier analysis in LCA group.

So my question is

> Is there a general method of Fourier analysis to solve the heat equation on LCA group, like $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb S$?

Any reference and any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you told the authors to the books you have in mind. These titles are too generic...

Comment: LCA groups have a fundamental structure theorem (say for connected Lie type group), which basically says that those LCAs are products of tori and copies of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: @Asaf, I wonder whether the questioner is curious about non-Lie groups, e.g., totally disconnected, and what sense can be made of classical issues there.

Comment: @paulgarrett En, I am curious about the existence of solution of heat equation, which is analogy to the situation in $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb S$.

Comment: @Asaf Is there any possibility to generalize the method to Nonabelian Lie group?

Comment: @gaoxinge, there isn't such a unfied structure theorem for general Lie groups, but much is known in the Nilpotent case, and obviously in the semisimple (and reductive) cases, but here most of the litreture would be in a more modern terms of representation theory and not heat-kernels (some still stay with formulation by green functions, for example in the Gelbart-Jacquet article). A good place to start wandering around is Paul's website, or Bump's book or Borel's book about SL2 (Ragunathan's book might also be of interest).

Comment: @gaoxinge, I recall once that Kazhdan told me that "classifying all the representation of a solvable group is impossible", and I've learnt (in the hard way), that you should take very seriously anything that David says.

Comment: @paulgarret, you may be right, and probably know about this subject more than I do (for sure in the totally disconnected case). 
How would a heat kernel look like on a building? (say spherical)?
Is there any sort of "Poincare sequence" for that settings? I tend to stay in the Archimedean world (or the adelic one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is a reference that covers what one can say about the heat equation on a locally compact abelian group. I do not know what this would say in general - for instance what is the heat equation on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

But things are known at least in the context of compact Lie groups. A reference for this is E. Stein's *Topics in Harmonic Analysis: Related to the Littlewood--Paley Theory* This is discussed briefly in the second chapter. A key tool in it is the Peter-Weyl theorem which you can think of as a non-abelian version of Fourier analysis.